# Hi! I want to retrieve who passed the decision split on the path level. Is it possible to achieve via SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

as subject saying, I'm trying to retrieve the contactKey of the records who passed the decision split in path level.

I'm not sure It's possible, but I want for you to share your idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with using MC REST API, you can use the [Download Journey History API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/downloadJourneyHistory.html)

Example call:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/download?columns=ContactKey
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
x-direct-pipe: true
{
   "definitionIds": ["YOUR PATH activity ID"],
   "statuses": ["complete"]
}
```

The Historical journey data only is retained for **30 days**.

In order to get the path activity ID:

If you are a Window user, you can press and hold "Alt" and "Shift" then click to the activity, it will show the Activity ID and a option to copy.

[image]

Comment: really thank you for your help. I'll try with that REST API

Comment: @SujinHwang kindly mark it as the accepted answer if you find it helpful :) Thanks